# JqueryUI Google Map will not Resize unless clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, google-maps-api-3, jquery-ui-tabs

I have written a click function that resizes and recenters the map when the map is clicked.

Is there a way to make the function run automatically when the Tab Loads?  This is the function.

```
            mapResize = function () {
                var mapFirstClick = false;
                var center = new google.maps.LatLng(32.565243, -97.130531);
                $("#tabs-4").click(function() {
                    mapFirstClick || setTimeout(function() {
                        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                        mapFirstClick = true;
                        map.setCenter(center);
                    }, 250);
                });
            },
```

You can see how it acts at http://l2technotes.dyndns.org by clicking on the Location tab,  the Map does not load correctly but if you Click on the map it resizes and recenters correctly which tells me the click function is working.

As always, any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: you are using jqueryUI  1.10 . Most of the ressources you'll find on the web  refer to 1.8 but there have been some major changes, e.g. in 1.10 there is no longer a show-event, use `activate` instead:

```
    $('#tabs').tabs({
        activate: function (event, ui) {
                    if (ui.newPanel.attr('id') =='tabs-4') {
                      ui.newPanel.click();
                    }
                  }
    });
```

The documentation for 1.10 you'll find here: http://api.jqueryui.com/1.10/tabs/

Comment: That is absolutely brilliant. Thank you for noth the code and pointing out the change in the documentation.  I am new to jquery and this project has been educational and frustrating.